# How do I use async tasks to update my .Net Core 3.1 page as various tasks are occurring sequentially?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-core, razor-pages, .net-core-3.1

I am getting more and more used to using `.Net Core` but have some 'simple' questions about using asychronous tasks.

I have read throught the .Net tutorials on Razor pages for web apps on MSDN/Microsot but I want to figure out how to:

1. Click a button on my page (page is `GetFiles.cs` and `GetFiles.cshtml.cs`) called "Get Files" - *think this isn't hard*
2. Button "Get Files" gets disabled and series of sequentail tasks starts - *disable button is simple* but ***how to call the tasks***
3. Page does not do a full refresh but ***keeps updating the page*** (appending text) as tasks are done - ***not sure on this***

   - When button gets disable text below says something like "Task started..."
   - First task gets started and queries a database and text gets appended to above prior to query as "Query started" and appended
     after query finishes "Query ended"
   - Next task starts and text is appended as "Create file started" and a file is created then with query data from above and
     then when it finishes text is appended as "File creation finished"

I see this method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    // Do the x number of tasks and updates in here (number of tasks my vary depending on query results)
        
    // return Page?
    return ?
}
```

What is the easiest way to make a progree/task loop like this?

Comment: What you're describing is done with JavaScript (or Blazor...), not C#

Comment: So this is not built in to the Razor/.Net Core pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Razor page generates all of the HTML for a page in one go and sends it to the browser as a response. You can't send part of the HTML and then update other parts incrementally without incorporating other technologies. If you have multiple background tasks running as part of the Razor page execution, they all have to complete before the HTML is rendered.

You could use [SignalR](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/aspnet/signalr) to update parts of the page based on changes on the server after the initial page has rendered, but it might be simpler to use [client side script to make various asynchronous calls](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/ajax#ajax-tools) ([XmlHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)) to [named handler methods](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/handler-methods#named-handler-methods) that are responsible for executing the background tasks and then update part of the page with the response to those calls.

Personally, I would use the Fetch API to call into named handler methods that return [partial views](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/ajax/partial-update) (snippets of HTML) for this, or if the web app relies heavily on this requirement, I would more likely build a [Blazor WebAssembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/blazor/) app.

Comment: I built out SPAs and am learning React/NextJS but wanted something simple in .NET Core for a small internal tool and didn't want to build out a full SPA, etc. and used to use JQuery but new to the Razor/.NET Core 3.1 patterns so looking for what was "proper". Will use Fetch and handler methods for the task.

Comment: I would use .NET 6 instead of .NET Core 3.1, because that version is out of support this December: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core

Comment: Thanks for all the info!